# process is not defined on hot reload

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, hot-reload

I have a react app made with create react app, and hot reloading kills the page entirely with the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

What's strange is that there seems to be an iframe injected which I never noticed before:

[image]

This iframe is added to the DOM as soon as I reload and breaks the page as well as preventing an update. I can't find any documentation on "iframe-bundle.js" online.

Edit: I tried deleting my node modules and any questionable imports (I temporarily installed `craco` prior). Still the same issue. It's incredibly annoying!

Edit 2: If I delete that iframe everything seems to return to normal, i.e. page updates and is interactable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it. I did 2 things:

- Updated npm to latest
- Updated react-scripts to latest

Not sure which one fixed it.

Comment: I got same issue today and updating `react-scripts` worked for me.

Comment: Try Chris’ answer below if you can’t easily upgrade to a new major version of react-scripts.

Answer (score 112):

Upgrading your application to CRA (react-scripts) v5 with `npm i react-scripts@latest` will fix the issue.

If your app is not able to be upgraded because dependencies are incompatible or you require node version < 14, you can try the following workaround which worked for me:

1. Revert back to CRA 4: `npm i --save-exact react-scripts@4.0.3`
2. Add react-error-overlay as a dev dependency: `npm i --save-dev react-error-overlay@6.0.9`
3. Then add the following line to your package.json

```
"resolutions": {
  "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
},
```

4. If you're using `NPM`, force your package-lock.json file to actually use 6.0.9 with `npx npm-force-resolutions`

   If you're using `Yarn`, just run `yarn install` and your resolutions will be applied and fix the issue

More info at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773

Comment: error is still appears but hot reload works

Comment: Thank you! I went back MONTHS in commit history and this was popping up when it never used to.  Could not track down the reason at all, and this was the only fix.  You are outstanding.  If anyone is seeing this error message even if it has nothing to do with iframe (only similarity for me was the error, not the scenario), try this option first. +1000.

Comment: updating react-scripts worked

Comment: `react-error-overlay` trick worked with react-scripts@4.0.3. Thank you!

Comment: worked like a charm! I didnt need to add the resolutions part in though

Comment: This finally worked for me! We're using pnpm on our monorepo project which as a unique way of handling package. Basically, it was keeping a 6.0.10 version in ./node_modules/.pnpm/.... ! Once I figured that out and deleted it, it was ok!

Comment: Excellent, it also worked for me without the resolution part.

Answer (score 10):

I recently had this issue aswell.
I did couple of things to make it work. You can try these aswell.

- Change the react-script version to 4.0.3 inside package.json.
- Add this to package.json, below the dependencies.

> "resolutions": { "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9" },

- Install react-error-overlay v6.0.9 inside your devDependencies.
- Remove your node_modules and package-lock.json.
- Do npm install and check that works.

Note: After doing the above steps I had to run npm install react-error-overlay@6.0.9 again to fix this issue.

Comment: Tkanks a lot ! I don't know why, my yarn.lock and react-error-overlay version was already v6.0.9, but I had to run 'yarn add react-error-overlay@6.0.9' to make it works 

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your react-scripts version is ^4.0.3, then install react-error-overlay as devDependencies using this command below:

`npm i -D react-error-overlay@6.0.9` on NPM

`yarn add -D react-error-overlay@6.0.9` on Yarn

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answers above, but non of those fixed the issue for me. What I did to solve this problem in my case was:

1. Delete node_modules
2. clearing the cache ->  `npm cache clean --force`
3. install the latest react-scripts version -> `npm i react-scripts@latest`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).