# Create-React-App creates this <iframe> that prevents me from clicking or editing directly the app unless I delete it in the elements browswer editor

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, create-react-app

I recently did a global install of create-react-app and am having an issue where sometimes, when I'm working on a project, instead of editing directly what I have rendered in , it creates this  container around the entire app.

Upon further inspection it looks like it is an  which is rendered in the browswer as this:

```html
<iframe style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;"></iframe>
```

I have screenshotted below what this ends up looking like in my app (the iframe is the orange text on the right), but it's super annoying and I've deleted the css props and cannot imagine what is causing this container around my app.

Has anyone else come across this? I have to delete this iframe to edit the elements directly from the browser but can't think why this is rendering each time I load the app in the browser.

[image]

Comment: This is a longshot and probably totally off, but maybe you have some chrome extension that adds an iframe. Is the behavior the same when you run in an incognito tab (where extensions are disabled)?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, @BasvanderLinden! It seems like it's a useEffect hook around my project...I still need to debug it more. It has an Init and a window parameter on it, so it might be an issue with something that needs to load before accessing the elements of the project. I'm getting warmer though!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [process is not defined on hot reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70357360/process-is-not-defined-on-hot-reload)

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing but it only appears on certain components using React.lazy. Still trying to figure out exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So after MUCH research and testing, I finally figured this out and I hope it can save anyone in the same situation I was in

I have found two solutions that can solve this, one with a `.env` file that sometimes works, and the other solution is with `css` that I want to say always will solve this issue.

## Fix #1: .env solution

In the root folder level (the same level as the .gitignore, package.json, README.md, yarn.lock, /src), create a `.env` file and include the following in it:

```sh
FAST_REFRESH=false
```

This sometimes works, but if this doesn't work after awhile, proceed to the second solution below.

## Fix #2: `App.css` fix to disable pointer-events for iframe

This solution is what has saved me a bunch. Basically what this solution fixes is the wrapping iframe around the html files that exist in an app in the React.js template.

In your global styles file, add the following property to an iframe element: `pointer-events: none`. I then import this css file into my JSX page so that it will remove this iframe wrapper around the page. This will disable the iframe overlay and allow you to effectively click anywhere within the window frame.

```css
iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Hopefully one of these solutions saves you hours of research and time

Comment: @toki 's answer above fixed this for me

Comment: fix 2 worked for me, but i wonder why this iframe even exist in my project? can't we remove that permanently?

Comment: Not only this ruins the click/devtools experience, that iframe also soemtimes throws an ambigous errors that crashes the whole app, it there a way to completely disable this?
Another reason to stay away from create react app that only gives more pain by adding suspicious behavior to app build and configure webpack yourself.

Comment: ```iframe``` answer fixed it for me. Helpful if you don't want to revert back to a different react-scripts version, as the github solution below suggests.

Comment: CSS simply bypasses the issues TBH. But `iframe` is still there. And the app process is still terminated. I wonder, someone has found actual fix.

Comment: Ideally, this shouldn't be the accepted answer. 
this one solves the root cause: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71069031/1513083 without patching anything unnecessarily

Answer (score 14):

I haven't tried it, but the accepted answer looks like it will just disable fast refresh all together which is not ideal so..

Take a look at this github issue response

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11880#issuecomment-1005409614

Specifically I only needed

```
// package.json

"resolutions": { "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9" },
```

Make sure to run `yarn` or `npm install` after updating

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Make sure you have react-error-overlay@6.0.9 and not 6.0.10. The problem was that react-scripts@4.0.3 does use react-error-overlay@6.0.9 in its package.json. However, since 6.0.10 is marked as a patch, npm does use v6.0.10 instead of v6.0.9.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I had some errors in my code, and after I fixed all the lint errors, the iframe disappeared
[see the detail here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Vfe.png)

Comment: This is because the iframe is the react error overlay misbehaving, so if you have errors that cause the error overlay to render it triggers the iframe to appear. Fixing the errors will prevent the overlay from trying to appear, but the overlay is still not working properly when it renders the empty iframe

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to disable all the iframes on a page, so I use this:

```
body > iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your css, this will hide the iframe and prevent it affecting your work

```
 iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: this will disable all `iframes` might be a bit overkill 

Comment: the ones you want to see, add `display: block or flex` to the style, problem  solved 

Answer (score 0):

Please check first if there are any errors or warnings on importing modules or images or others types. Also there may be any packages or modules installed which is old version or have warnings or errors. You may find it on console. After fixing that, hopefully it will fixed.

I found fixed on me.

Answer (score 0):

Update your BrowserList in package.json file with this: `"browserslist": [ ">0.2%", "not dead", "not ie <= 11", "not op_mini all" ]`

This was a fix for me in same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still encountering this issue (most likely by cloning a repo that is using an old version of `react-scripts`), you can fix it by updating `react-scripts` to `v5.0.1` (or later).

```
npm install --save react-scripts@5
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Remove your package-lock.json
2. Remove your react-scripts dependency from your package.json
3. Run `npm install --save react-scripts`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74502897/15684543