# In React app, iframe is showing up in developer tools, elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

Its First time im asking a question, so not much idea how to describe/write it.

I am working in a react project (making clons for learning purpose). Watching video tutorials and first time use firebase and redux. After making much progress, I counter the problem, in which when I save my work, local host 3000 doesn't refresh. I know there are lot of answers, I tried all but they didn't work for me.

**But the main issue** is, In my developer tool i see

`<iframe style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;"></iframe>`

Within this, there is `#document` and inside of it, `<html> then <head> and <body>.`

I didn't know what is this and the reason why it's showing up. Then i search, what is iframe, but i never use such thing i my project. And after a lot of research how to remove it. I didn't find the answer and way to do it [Screen shot of my developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8hVK.png).

I can see all my components but they don't respond to me E.g can't take inputs, no hover effects etc. But when i manually delete `<iframe>` from dev tool, it works fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is used by react to inject changes to the dom during hotreload. Sometimes it fails and doesn't remove the iframe, thus the behavior.

A fix would be to add:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
```

To your package.json immediately after the scripts, delete package.lock or yarn.lock files, install packages again.

Comment: it didn't solve the problem, But I got the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70499543/create-react-app-creates-this-iframe-that-prevents-me-from-clicking-or-editing) but yes still didn't fix the error in console. You can check get more clear understanding of related issue on Github [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your browserlist in package.json file with this code:

```
"browserslist": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not ie <= 11",
"not op_mini all"
]
```

and make sure you are not having errors. This was a quick fix