# create-react-app application becomes non-interactive after fast refresh

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have noticed that with the latest version of create-react-app (react-scripts@5.0.0, also had this problem in the latest @4.x.x version) the page becomes non-interactive after fast refresh. By non-interactive, I mean that I cannot click, drag, select or perform any other mouse action on it.

I disabled fast refresh by adding FAST_REFRESH=false to the .env file and everything worked fine, but fast refresh is very useful once your project gets big and takes longer to compile.

By default the react-scripts (in the project, not globally) version was @0.9.5, but I had to change it to @^4.0.3 for it to work (app does not work properly with @0.9.5).

I am running Linux 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser console for errors. I was seeing a similar error with Node@12.16.0 and React-Scripts@4.0.3. When a page crashes or freezes like that the console is a good place to look.

The solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70402397/11833439). In my case I just added the resolution and ran npm install.